# Can not connect to mysql database using Django

Tags: python, django, mysql-connector

I'm trying to connect my Django app with MySQL and I have Successfully installed MySQL-connector-python-2.0.4 also. But after that whenever I run server same error message is showing.

Here are my cmd ...

[image: error]
[image: error code]

Here is the full message showing

Comment: this is unreadable, add please text instead of images

Comment: What does the last line say?

Answer (score 1):

you are installing `MySQL connector` for python (not recommended), you need the `MySQLdb` module, refer to this official recommendation from django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers
and install `mysqlclient` *it is a native driver and It’s the recommended choice.*

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

for further informations have a look at this medium post : https://medium.com/@omaraamir19966/connect-django-with-mysql-database-f946d0f6f9e3